# How to resize the root file system of my installation?

Tags: disk-management

i have gparted install.

mine file system is 60 gb 
and other drive is around 15gb

I want to add around 40gb to other drive

where mine file system will be 20gb and
other drive to be 55gb

How can I achieve that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it sounds like you are trying to do this while the system is running ... I think what you need to do is get another like distro to boot from that has gparted on it (or another partition tool that you can use) ... THEN run gparted on your disk (be careful) ... resize the partitions to your liking ... do NOT delete partitions or you will lose your data ... you want to RESIZE each partition ... so for your example, the 60 GB partition you would shrink to 20 GB then expand the other partition to 55 GB ... This is assuming that you are using less than 20 GB on the first

Comment: you mean like gparted live on usb and select usb from boot options and partition the file system

Comment: yup ... you got it